# Why does angular2 not find the stylesheet that is imported in index.html?

Tags: angular

I have an angular2 app with an index.html file. I have this line in index.html

> link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css"

The style sheet is there, and is actually loaded, because it affects the page by applying the styles defined in styles.css.

But this error is thrown in the console.

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found)

I have had this error for a while, and always thought I would deal with it later, and thought it had to do with an old version of angular 2. But now I am on 2.3.1 and the error is still thrown in the console. How can I solve this?

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>MemberAdmin</title>
  <base href="/">

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">

  <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/IndexResources/jquery.js"></script>

  <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css" media="all">-->

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">


  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


  <!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/IndexResources/angular-calendar.css">-->

  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand" rel="stylesheet">


  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="./assets/smalllogo.png">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

Folder structure:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Maybe you don't need that style?

Try to remove it and see if the error message is gone, and the styles stay the same.

Comment: Can you include your full `index.html` and your folder structure please?

Comment: Yes, I will do that asap

Comment: Done, added the stuff you wanted @echonax.

Comment: @Dan why do you have  <base href="/">
?

Comment: Are you using angular-cli ?

Comment: @Sajeetharan I haven't looked at that in a while, I have been working on this app since RC1, and I remember there was a time period where the '/' was required <base href="/">

Comment: @YounesM yes I am using the cli

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since ou're using `@angular/cli` you don't need to add your css to the index, just add the path of your stylesheet in the `.angular-cli.json` file.

```
"styles": [
  "styles.css",
  "css/spinner.css", 
  "css/bootstrap.min.css",
  "css/font-awesome.min.css"
],
```